# Crystal Report referring to xsd file

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a crystal report, but I want the connection string that I have mentioned in the Web.Config file to be accessed. Also, I want to create an xsd file for my crystal report file to refer. Can someone please direct me to a tutorial or forum to solve my problem?

Comment: When you use the dataset designer, it will prompt for the connection string from config, or enable you to save the connection string to config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also programatically set the report data source if you need to - I can provide details if you require

between calling myReportDocument.Load("myreport.rpt") and myReportDocument.Refresh() (the latter of which actually gets the data from the database) it is possible to add a call to myReportDocument.SetDataSource(myDataSource) which takes an object of data source type, which you can create, with a call to its constructors, with the URL of the data source you wish to use, its username and password.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for helping me out.
I am now able to display data in the crystal report file using the XSD file.
The xsd file has fields which are exactly the same name as mentioned in the select query that is bringing values from DB. 
The following is the part of the xsd file that contains the field names in the xs:element tag.

The datatypes of these fields , also needs to be mentioned. The XSD file name can be kept as desired.
The name "Summary_Report_on_portal" and  "Summary_Updt" does not correspond to any dataset name in code behind or query fields. It can be kept as per the user's wish.

This XSD file needs to be referred into the crystal report, using the Database Expert in the Field Explorer window.  The "Summary_Updt" name is visible in the new connections , which can be added to the crystal report.
The fields mentioned in the xs:element field are visible for the user to drag and drop into the crystal report. 
When the user mentions the data source to the crystal report(dataset), the fields in the dataset are matched with the XSD field values.
CODE:
objBL.Rpt.SetDataSource(objBL.ds_shipment_info.Tables[0]);

Hope this is detailed enough. Let me know if anyone wants more info

Answer (score 0):

a different way would be to call ReportDocument::SetDatabaseLogon (String * user, String * password, String * server, String * database); before Refresh(); if you don't want to reuse a connection. This has the benefit of being simple but means that you dont reuse data sources.