# Import existing report lost .xsd file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I imported the .rpt file as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317714/clone-or-copy-of-existing-crystal-reports). But when trying to run the option `"Log On or Off Server..."`, the Report interface is requesting a .xsd file.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675174/crystal-report-referring-to-xsd-file) the .xsd file is stored in the report. But my .xsd file is missing, it's not inside or outside the report.

So why is the .xsd file supposedly lost when i import an .rpt from another project?

Comment: I can't say "why". But if you are using a typed DataSet, you can generate the XSD file from the DataSet using the method WriteXmlSchema.